# Find remainder in binomial expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients

[image]

In the question how they got $\lambda = 2^{1008}$?

Comment: You are right. As $\binom nr=\binom n{n-r}$

$$2\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2n+1}r=(1+1)^{2n+1}$$

Now as $2^5\equiv-1\pmod{33},2^{10}\equiv1$

$1008\equiv8\pmod{10}\implies2^{1008}\equiv2^8\pmod{33}\equiv25$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.